# Is it possible to generate a ciphertext with less characters than the plaintext?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

Does a cipher exist that can take in a plaintext that is x characters long and returns a ciphertext that is less than x characters long, but that can be decrypted back to the original plaintext? What if the alphabet for the ciphertext is much bigger than the alphabet for the plaintext?

Comment: Without assumptions (= for the general case), this is impossible. See limits of compression / pigeonhole-principle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about crypto, not programming. This kind of question has been answered before though.

Answer (score 6):

No, this is not possible by using a cipher.

For a generic cipher that allows any message with equal probability, it is theoretically - and therefore practically - impossible that it can compress the message in any meaningful way. Generally, it is not a function of a cipher to perform any kind of compression anyway, and generally a modern ciphers are written to operate on any kind of binary encoded message.

Due to the pigeonhole principle there must be at least as many ciphertext possible as plaintext. Otherwise one ciphertext will map to multiple plaintext, and there is no way you can decide which one would be the original plaintext.

Generally, if a key is reused, it is even required to add an IV to be secure. If no IV or other unique value is added then repeated plaintext will generate identical ciphertext, leaking information to an adversary, so commonly the ciphertext is even expanded. Nowadays we also often add an authentication tag so an adversary can not change the ciphertext undetected.

If if doesn't matter for your application that repeated plaintext result in identical ciphertext then there are relatively complex techniques that allow you to "break even". These techniques are called Format Preserving Encryption or FPE. If you're lucky enough that the plaintext size is identical to the block size then you could also simply perform a single block encrypt using any block cipher.

---

If you want to reduce message size then you need to somehow compress your input plaintext. This can for instance be performed by a generic compression routine on either binary or textual data. Often it is also possible to re-encode the message at the application level (enum instead of string) or representation level (binary instead of text) very effectively.

Finally, there is also a "cryptographic compression", which is performed in secure hash algorithms such as SHA-256. However, SHA-256 is a *one-way* hash function, making it impossible to retrieve your message. Hashing is used to create a unique fingerprint over the message; it doesn't provide *confidentiality* of the message as would be expected by a cipher.

Comment: Felt like typing an answer with a very easy to understand description of the problem. I'll save it in a text file locally, so feel free to delete. Khaja, if you don't understand anything of this question, please let me know in a comment below. I'll use you to proof-read if you don't mind :)

Comment: This explanation is clear .Thank you Maarten!