# How to create fixed length decryption

Tags: encryption

I would like to ask if there is a way to encrypt text (no matter how long it is) and ALWAYS get a fixed length decryption? I am not referring to hashing but to encryption/decryption.

Example:
Suppose that we want to encrypt (not hash) a text which is 60 characters long. The result will be a string which is 32 characters long. We can then decrypt the string to get the original text!

We now want to encrypt (not hash) a text which is 200 characters long. The result will be a string which is again 32 characters long. We can then decrypt the string to get the original text!

Is that somehow possible?

Thank you

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Usually we'd use compress then encrypt, but beware that the ciphertext length may allow an attacker to infer more information than you might expect if compression is used.

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as perfect compression. If you could compress a random sequence then you could repeat that compression until you compress a movie into a single byte.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to generate a ciphertext with less characters than the plaintext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53895151/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-ciphertext-with-less-characters-than-the-plaintext)

Answer (score 2):

As the comments indicate, this is impossible. For the underlying reason that this is impossible, see [the Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). In your example, there are 256^200 inputs and 256^32 outputs. Therefore there must be at least 1 output that has more than 1 input, and therefore is impossible to reverse. Since the number of inputs is massively larger than the number of outputs (and in the general case, is unbounded), [almost all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_all) cipher texts are necessarily impossible to decrypt.

Comment: thank you all for your time to answer! :-)